# How to find files from path from script argument list?

Tags: bash, file, find

Easy question but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I want to find all files from path which was passed as a script argument.
So what I'm doing is:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$1 
find $path -type f
```

When I'm running the script nothing happens, any ideas?

Comment: That should work. How are you running the script? Show us some sample input and output.

Comment: . example.sh /home/xxx/xxx/xxx - this is input, I got no output.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: It doesn't appear to be the problem here, but you should be quoting the parameter expansion anyway: `find "$path" -type f`. (The exact value of `/home/xxx/xxx/xxx` could make a difference, though.)

Comment: Yea I already tried it, that's not it

Comment: May be you have tried with empty directory. Code looks good and argument should be path to directory not to file.

Comment: What does `ls /home/xxx/xxx/xxx` show? Is that really a non-empty directory?

Comment: Yes, I create two txt files in that directory, when I'm using ls or even find in console it works, but script still gives me nothing on output

Comment: Are you supplying an absolute path or a relative path that exists in the path that you are executing the script?

Comment: As @Cyrus pointed out, you should run the script as "bash -x path/to/script.sh $path" in order to debug it.

Comment: And you should provide more info on the output of the script, on the contents of the path, and the output of the find command when you run it interactively from the shell.

Comment: Parameters to the file in the source command are an *extension* to the POSIX standard, so it is possible that you are not executing the `.` from `bash` but from some other POSIX compliant shell.  In this case the `#!` line will be ignored.  @W.Mann alluded to this in his (now deleted) answer.  Try running the script normally without the `.` command.  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/